# Compilation error in Scala macro for generic type

Tags: scala, generics, macros

I am trying to write a macro that implicitly materializes Play Formatter instances when they are required:

```
class FormattableImpl(override val c: whitebox.Context) extends Utils(c) {
    import c.universe._

    def materializeFormatImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[play.api.libs.json.Format[T]] = {
        val tpe = implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe
        val x = c.Expr[play.api.libs.json.Format[T]](q" com.ubookr.macros.Json.format[$tpe] ")
        println(show(x))
        x
    }
}

object Format {
    implicit def materializeFormat[T]: play.api.libs.json.Format[T] = macro FormattableImpl.materializeFormatImpl[T]
}
```

This works just fine for non-parameterized types (eg.

```
case class Apple(id: Long, name: String)
val x = materializeFormat[Apple]
```

).

It also works for collections

```
val xx = materializeFormat[Seq[Apple]]
```

When I try to use it for my own parameterized type, however, it loses the value of the type parameter:

```
case class Proxy[+T](id: Long, name: String)
val xxx = materializeFormat[Proxy[Apple]]
```

which responds with

```
[error] package.scala:112: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.OFormat[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Nothing]]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Format[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple]]
[error] Note: com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Nothing] <: com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple], but trait Format is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]     val xxx: Any = com.ubookr.macros.Format.materializeFormat[Proxy[Apple]]
[error]
```

This makes sense because WeakTypeTag doesn't know about T. My first question is *why does this work correctly with Seq??*

However, I came up with what I think should be a feasible workaround:

```
def materializeProxy[T]: play.api.libs.json.Format[Proxy[T] = macro FormattableImpl.materializeProxyImpl[T]
```

where the implementation of `materializeProxyImpl` is

```
def materializeProxyImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[play.api.libs.json.Format[Proxy[T]]] = materializeFormatImpl[Proxy[T]]
```

the `println` in `materializeFormatImpl` now *correctly* shows the actual value of parameter type t:

```
Expr[play.api.libs.json.Format[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple]]](com.ubookr.macros.Json.format[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple]])
```

but I am still getting the same error immediately after:

```
[error] package.scala:112: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.OFormat[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Nothing]]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Format[com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple]]
[error] Note: com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Nothing] <: com.ubookr.macros.Proxy[Apple], but trait Format is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]     val xxx: Any = Format.materializeProxy[Apple]
[error]
```

I have tried changing the type annotation on both `materializeProxy` and `materializeProxyImpl` to `Any` and `Tree` respectively, but the syntax error still occurs, which suggests to me that the type mismatch is happening somewhere internal to the macro engine.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in the macro engine?

Comment: Hmm, I think that the fact that it works correctly for Seq is a clue. The JsMacroImpl code has explicit helpers for Seq parameters. I suspect that the error is occurring because the play macro is ignoring my type parameter.

Comment: This was a known limitation, now fixed: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the play json macro implementation didn't expect generic case classes. It was outputting

```
(
     (JsPath \ "id").format[Long] and
     (JsPath \ "name").format[String]
)(Proxy.apply, unlift(Proxy.unapply)
```

I amended the play macro so that it outputs

```
(
     (JsPath \ "id").format[Long] and
     (JsPath \ "name").format[String]
)(Proxy.apply[Apple], unlift(Proxy.unapply[Apple])
```

and now it works as expected.